# Calculating entropic penalties for homochiral aggregation

Tags: statistical-mechanics

*Disclaimer: I am a chemist with a strong interest in physics, and lately I have been toying with this problem in my spare time. I feel it is appropriate to ask here cause it involves some statistical mechanics and simple combinatorics, and not a whole lot of chemistry. Plus, I thought it would make for some interesting cross-disciplinary discussion. Correct me if I am wrong*

**Background**

Some molecules have a handedness; these two stereiosmers are mirror images of each other. In many experiments, it has been observed that molecules prefere to form homochiral clusters/assemblies.

**Model**

We chemists often label these mirror-image molecules with *R*- or *S*- labels. So we can just represent the molecules as coins with two faces-a black face, or a white face (each corresponding to one of the stereochemistry label). A cluster will be a collection of these coins.

Let us ignore all enthalpic terms, and focus entirely on entropy.

Say, we have a cluster of 9 molecules (a 9mer)-if it is derived from an enatiopure solution (i.e only R- or only S- present), we can only arrive at one possible structure-either all black, or all white coins.

If we have a racemic starting solution (50-50 black and white coins), we have $2^9$ possible structures, which ought to follow the binomial distribution.

Example:  $1(9S), 9(8S/1R), 36(7S/2R), 84(6S/3R), 126(5S/4R), 126(4S/5R), 84(S/6R), 36(2S/7R), 9(1S/8R), and 1(9R)$.

The probability that a cluster of size N molecules, comprises of n molecules of a given enantiomer, $P = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}p^n(1-p)^{N-n}$

for an ideal racemic cluster p = 0.5

Now, we wish to account for the entropy related to the number of permutations that lead to equivalent structures by exchanging non-distinguishable molecules.

For a homochiral structure (all S or all R), there will be $N!$ states, where $N$ is the number of molecules.

For a racemic system, just doing some simple examples on paper, I feel 
there will also be $N!$ equivalent states for a cluster comprising of N
molecules. Basically, I am searching for the number of permutations that lead to equivalent structures.

(1) How could one show/prove this in general?

I think an illustration would be helpful at this point. This is the kind of coin based model I am referring to. For an 9mer, the first cluster is what I call homochiral. The second, third, fourth and fifth would be racemic clusters (an ideal racemic cluster will have 1:1 black and white coins, but that is not possible with 9 coins). Anyway, each of these structures have a multiplicity for example, structure 4 and 5 are essentially the same structure and can be obtained by a simple rotation. Two more structures exist in this family, thus structure 5 has a multiplicity of 4.

So a more realistic estimate would be $\frac{2^9}{4}$ (?) Not sure about this, I would love to hear someone's opinion on this.

(2) In general, for an N-mer, can we place an estimate on the multiplicity possesed by the largest set of structures.

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting and difficult problem, but may I ask what your motivation is? Because I imagine these molecules usually reside in solution for which solvation entropy (not included in what you're calculating) usually dominates the total entropy. So I'm not sure how useful the configurational entropy alone would even be...

Comment: It was a back of the envelope kind of thing which started becoming complex as I proceeded. I absolutely agree with you, but perhaps it has some pedagogic value